# Custom JUnit RunnerBuilder

Tags: java, junit

How can I tell JUnit to use a custom `RunnerBuilder` implementation of my own creation?

Using a custom `Runner` is as simple as providing the `@RunWith` annotation. I can't see how I'd then tell JUnit which `RunnerBuilder` to use though.

[The example in the JavaDoc](http://junit.org/javadoc/latest/org/junit/runners/model/RunnerBuilder.html) still doesn't show how a `RunnerBuilder` would be specified.

Comment: The documentation says "*A custom runner class with a constructor taking a RunnerBuilder parameter **will be passed** the instance of RunnerBuilder*". How it's created falls under the category of "implementation details", which you shouldn't worry about

Comment: How does JUnit know which RunnerBuilder to pass? Looking at the source code all I can see are JUnit default RunnerBuilders.

Comment: @Deejay As a backup plan, you could always ignore the supplied `RunnerBuilder` and use your own inside your `Runner`.

Comment: @Duncan - do you want to list that as an answer so I can credit you? That's exactly what I ended up doing.

Comment: @Deejay It may be better if you write the answer, giving some example code snippets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following @Duncan's suggestion I didn't bother with a `RunnerBuilder` and instead opted to have my `Runner` implementation do annotation look-ups itself.

In this instance I have one runner delegating to another, defined by an annotation, and also using another annotation to define classes that should be loaded by a different classloader.

The runner:

```
public QuarantiningRunner(Class<?> testFileClass) throws InitializationError
{
    delegateRunningToDiscoverer = new DelegateRunningToDiscoverer();
    quarantinedPatternDiscoverer = new QuarantinedPatternDiscoverer();
    Class<? extends Runner> delegateRunningTo = delegateRunningToDiscoverer.getDelegateRunningToOn(testFileClass);
    ...
```

One of the annotation discoverers:

```
public class DelegateRunningToDiscoverer
{
    public Class<? extends Runner> getDelegateRunningToOn(Class<?> testClass)
    {
        Class<? extends Runner> runnerClass = BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.class;
        DelegateRunningTo annotation = testClass.getAnnotation(DelegateRunningTo.class);

        if(annotation != null)
        {
            runnerClass = annotation.value();
        }

        return runnerClass;
    }
}
```